# What is ~/.cache/weather.xml?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cache, conky

I use [a clock-date-weather conky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214946/32012) and I noticed that it is related to the file `~/.cache/weather.xml`.

I am curious: was this file created by conky or by what other program? Is it present on the system by default? Can it be edited? Is it generated at a certain point and can be safely deleted?

What are its main purposes?

It has this content (but which is changed on disk by `~/.conkyrc` or mayby my `curl`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
        <rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
            <channel>

<title>Yahoo! Weather - London, GB</title>
<link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/London__GB/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/UKXX0085_c.html</link>
<description>Yahoo! Weather for London, GB</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 10 Jul 2015 9:49 am BST</lastBuildDate>
<ttl>60</ttl>
<yweather:location city="London" region=""   country="United Kingdom"/>
<yweather:units temperature="C" distance="km" pressure="mb" speed="km/h"/>
<yweather:wind chill="21"   direction="160"   speed="12.87" />
<yweather:atmosphere humidity="40"  visibility="9.99"  pressure="1015.92"  rising="0" />
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="4:53 am"   sunset="9:14 pm"/>
<image>
<title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
<width>142</width>
<height>18</height>
<link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
<url>http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif</url>
</image>
<item>
<title>Conditions for London, GB at 9:49 am BST</title>
<geo:lat>51.51</geo:lat>
<geo:long>-0.13</geo:long>
<link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/London__GB/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/UKXX0085_c.html</link>
<pubDate>Fri, 10 Jul 2015 9:49 am BST</pubDate>
<yweather:condition  text="Fair"  code="34"  temp="21"  date="Fri, 10 Jul 2015 9:49 am BST" />
<description><![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/34.gif"/><br />
<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
Fair, 21 C<BR />
<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
Fri - Mostly Sunny. High: 26 Low: 14<br />
Sat - Mostly Sunny. High: 27 Low: 15<br />
Sun - Showers. High: 22 Low: 14<br />
Mon - Cloudy. High: 24 Low: 16<br />
Tue - AM Showers. High: 23 Low: 12<br />
<br />
<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/London__GB/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/UKXX0085_c.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
]]></description>
<yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="10 Jul 2015" low="14" high="26" text="Mostly Sunny" code="34" />
<yweather:forecast day="Sat" date="11 Jul 2015" low="15" high="27" text="Mostly Sunny" code="34" />
<yweather:forecast day="Sun" date="12 Jul 2015" low="14" high="22" text="Showers" code="11" />
<yweather:forecast day="Mon" date="13 Jul 2015" low="16" high="24" text="Cloudy" code="26" />
<yweather:forecast day="Tue" date="14 Jul 2015" low="12" high="23" text="AM Showers" code="39" />
<guid isPermaLink="false">UKXX0085_2015_07_14_7_00_BST</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>

<!-- fan1678.sports.bf1.yahoo.com Fri Jul 10 02:28:42 PDT 2015 -->
```

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on "a conky". Put up its code?

Comment: So maybe it's because of "http://weather.yahooapis.fr/forecastrss"?

Comment: @DKBose - "because of" : I guess you comment on the other question, "why are the days in English?"

Comment: @DKBose - Please take a look at my other question that I just updated, discussing both files.

Comment: @DKBose - I've inserted the link to the conky question into the one above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Was this file created by conky or by what other program?*

It looks like it was created by the conky weather program.  Type `lsof ~/.cache/weather.xml` to know which process is using this file.

*Is it present on the system by default?*

I'd say certainly not, it looks created by that conky program.

*Can it be edited?*

Sure, if you want it to display incorrect information...

*Is it generated at a certain point and can be safely deleted?
What are its main purposes?*

It looks like a local cache for the weather forecast.  If you delete it, the weather program will just fetch back the data from its provider, Yahoo! Weather.

Comment: great. would you take a look at the linked question?